# Multi criteria count in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help in Excel to……

```
Count If
    Status is P (Column C)
        If Employee name is Harry (Column A)
            If Month is Oct 2015 (Column B) (Monthly attendance)
                If it’s not Sat or Sun (Column B)
                    If the date is not declared as holiday in holiday list. (Column f)
```

[image: Style sheet]

Comment: What have you already tried? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: could you please post the example as data, it's very difficult to work with it now.

Comment: Not tested, `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A23 = "Henry")*(MONTH(B2:B23)=10)*(YEAR(B2:B23)=2015)*(WEEKDAY(B2:B23,2)<6)*(ISERROR(MATCH(B2:B23,G2:G18,0))))`

Answer (score 0):

Your Check-in date is kind of in an ugly format. It resists standard WEEKDAY, MONTH, YEAR etc. formulas, at least for me (Excel 2010, U.S. American). This means we'll have to do a few extra steps.

In column D, we can extract the month. Use the following:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ", 100)),100,100))
```

This grabs the text between the first 2 spaces.

In column E, we can grab the day of the week. Use the following:

```
=LEFT(B2, (FIND(",", B2, 1)-1))
```

This grabs the text to the left of the first comma.

Finally, in column F, we can grab the year.

```
=RIGHT(B2, 4)
```

At this point, I'd insert a column between your remaining stuff to push the holidays one over. Then, you can flag every record that is in scope with the following formula in G.

This checks that C2 = P, A2 = Harry, it's October 2015, E2 is a weekday, and it's not in your array of holidays.

```
=AND(C2 = "P", A2 = "Harry", D2 = "October", F2 = "2015", 
E2 <> "Saturday", E2 <> "Sunday", ISERROR(MATCH(B2, H$2:H$18, 0)))
```

From there, you can just do a COUNTIF formula on column G.

```
=COUNTIF(G:G, TRUE)
```